# Ruby beginner - need help optimising this code

Tags: ruby, algorithm, optimization, enumerable

Currently in the process of learning Ruby/programming in general, and I came across this question:

> Your task is to construct a building which will be a pile of n cubes. The cube at the bottom will have a volume of `n^3`, the cube above will have volume of `(n-1)^3` and so on until the top which will have a volume of `1^3`.
>   You are given the total volume `m` of the building. Being given `m` can you find the number `n` of cubes you will have to build?
>   The parameter of the function `findNb(find_nb, find-nb)` will be an integer `m` and you have to return the integer `n` such as `n^3 + (n-1)^3 + ... + 1^3 = m` if such a `n` exists or `-1` if there is no such `n*`.

and here is my attempt to solve this:

```
def find_nb(m)
  (1..Float::INFINITY).each do |n|
    if (1..n).inject(0) {|sum, value| sum + value**3} == m
      return p n 
    else
      next
    end
  end
end
```

This seems to work ok with inputs that I know will work such as:

```
find_nb(4183059834009)
find_nb(135440716410000)
find_nb(40539911473216)
```

Areas I need help in:

- I don't know how i would get it to understand when there is no value of `n` that would satisfy the equation and therefore output `-1` for an input such as

  ```
  find_nb(24723578342962)
  ```
- Any tips on how to make the existing code better would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The answers have covered most of the important points, but I think it's worth repeating that it's important to look for optimizations in a problem itself. Since you know that the `n^3 + (n - 1)^3 + ...` sum is equal to *m*, you know that `n^3` cannot be larger than *m* (the bound is obviously stricter than this, but it's an easy starting point). Because of that, you know that there's no point in searching *n* values above the cube root of *m*.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squared_triangular_number

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint 1: You don't need to go to infinity: after a certain `n`, the sum will be greater than `m`, and rapidly getting further away.

Hint 2: If the `n` is found, the function will never reach its last line, because of `return`.

Hint 3: `next` is automatic if you reach the end of `each` block.

Hint 4: The sum of cubes does not need to be recalculated from scratch each time. You are not making a whole new building, you're just putting a larger cube underneath.

So...

```
def find_nb(m)
  n = 1
  sum = 1
  while sum < m
    n += 1
    sum += n**3
  end
  return sum == m ? n : -1
end
```

Edit: Here's a functional version, but I think the plain `while` above is still much clearer (and probably faster, too):

```
def find_nb(m)
  sum = 0
  sizes = 1.upto(Float::INFINITY)
    .lazy
    .map { |n| sum += n ** 3 }
    .take_while { |x| x <= m }
    .to_a
  sizes.last == m ? sizes.length : -1
end
```

Comment: Beat me to me it!  Great explanation, I'd just add that you can return `-1` in any case where your `sum` exceeds `m`.  Also the return is optional in ruby but here it's more explicit

Comment: @Anthony: "you can return `-1` in any case where your `sum` exceeds `m`": if you check the logic, that is exactly what I am doing. It will not happen as long as `while` is still going.

Comment: Yep we're on the same page, I just meant in your written explanation (separate from your code), to help drive home your answer.

Answer (score 1):

#### Fixing/Improving your code

To fix your code, create another branch in your `if-statement` telling your iteration when to return `-1`. `next` is not required in an `each` iteration (credit to @Amadan for pointing this out).

Note, that it's best not to print anything from the method definition. Print when calling the method. Indentation and spacing has been improved. Also note I'm defining the sum of the cubes in a variable `total`:

```
def find_nb m
  (1..Float::INFINITY).each do |n|
    total = (1..n).inject(0) { |sum, value| sum + value**3 }
    if total == m
      return n 
    elsif total > m
      return -1
    end
  end
end

find_nb 4183059834009   #=> 2022
find_nb 135440716410000 #=> 4824
find_nb 40539911473216  #=> 3568
find_nb 37              #=> -1
```

---

#### Further improvements

If you wish to use an infinite loop, Ruby has `loop`. Use this with `with_index` like so:

```
def find_nb m
  loop.with_index(1) do |_,n|
    t = (1..n).inject { |sum,i| sum + i**3 }
    if t == m
      return n            
    elsif t > m
      return -1        
    end
  end
end

find_nb 4183059834009   #=> 2022
find_nb 135440716410000 #=> 4824
find_nb 40539911473216  #=> 3568
find_nb 37              #=> -1
```